# computed column - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'when'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, case, calculated-columns

I'm trying to add a computed column to a SQL Server 2008 Express table.

The formula is:

```
case when callrecord_contacttype=1 then 'Routed voice' 
else when callrecord_contacttype=2 then 'Direct incoming voice' 
else when callrecord_contacttype=3 then 'Direct outgoing voice' 
else when callrecord_contacttype=4 then 'Direct internal voice' 
else when callrecord_contacttype=5 then 'Routed callback' 
else when callrecord_contacttype=6 then 'Routed email' 
else when callrecord_contacttype=7 then 'Direct outgoing email' 
else when callrecord_contacttype=8 then 'Routed chat' else '' end
```

But I'm getting the error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'when'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try :

```
case callrecord_contacttype
    when 1 then 'Routed voice' 
    when 2 then 'Direct incoming voice' 
    when 3 then 'Direct outgoing voice' 
    when 4 then 'Direct internal voice' 
    when 5 then 'Routed callback' 
    when 6 then 'Routed email' 
    when 7 then 'Direct outgoing email' 
    when 8 then 'Routed chat'
    else ''
end
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx for syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Have only 1 `ELSE` in your query:

```
case when callrecord_contacttype=1 then 'Routed voice' 
when callrecord_contacttype=2 then 'Direct incoming voice' 
when callrecord_contacttype=3 then 'Direct outgoing voice' 
when callrecord_contacttype=4 then 'Direct internal voice' 
when callrecord_contacttype=5 then 'Routed callback' 
when callrecord_contacttype=6 then 'Routed email' 
when callrecord_contacttype=7 then 'Direct outgoing email' 
when callrecord_contacttype=8 then 'Routed chat' 
else '' end
```

Answer (score 2):

`else` only belongs on the final, non-conditional clause:

```
case when callrecord_contacttype=1 then 'Routed voice' 
     when callrecord_contacttype=2 then 'Direct incoming voice' 
     when callrecord_contacttype=3 then 'Direct outgoing voice' 
     when callrecord_contacttype=4 then 'Direct internal voice' 
     when callrecord_contacttype=5 then 'Routed callback' 
     when callrecord_contacttype=6 then 'Routed email' 
     when callrecord_contacttype=7 then 'Direct outgoing email' 
     when callrecord_contacttype=8 then 'Routed chat'
     else '' end
```

Answer (score 2):

Only one `else` can be in `case`. [Look at examples](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

```
case when callrecord_contacttype=1 then 'Routed voice' 
     when callrecord_contacttype=2 then 'Direct incoming voice' 
     when callrecord_contacttype=3 then 'Direct outgoing voice' 
     when callrecord_contacttype=4 then 'Direct internal voice' 
     when callrecord_contacttype=5 then 'Routed callback' 
     when callrecord_contacttype=6 then 'Routed email' 
     when callrecord_contacttype=7 then 'Direct outgoing email' 
     when callrecord_contacttype=8 then 'Routed chat' 
else '' end
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the Else's then try again.

```
case when callrecord_contacttype=1 then 'Routed voice' 
when callrecord_contacttype=2 then 'Direct incoming voice' 
when callrecord_contacttype=3 then 'Direct outgoing voice' 
when callrecord_contacttype=4 then 'Direct internal voice' 
when callrecord_contacttype=5 then 'Routed callback' 
when callrecord_contacttype=6 then 'Routed email' 
when callrecord_contacttype=7 then 'Direct outgoing email' 
when callrecord_contacttype=8 then 'Routed chat' else '' end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    CASE @TestVal
    WHEN 1 THEN 'First'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Second'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'Third'
    ELSE 'Other'
END
```

Probably you can try changing it to 
case callrecord_contacttype 
when 1 then 'Routed voice' 
when 2 then 'Direct incoming voice' 
etc